# Is there any general framework to test In-Memory databases

Tags: java, database, in-memory-database

I have to test and benchmark with few In-Memory databases like hazelcast, gridgain,redis. Is there any common utility for such thing which provide
1) Loading data into it
2) Check SQL Support
3) Transaction Support
4) ACID property support

So that for each In-Memory database I have to just write adapter classes for these module

Comment: hazelcast is easy as hell to use, you should also check for infinispan specially if you are on jboss.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at to the Yahoo! Cloud Serving Benchmark [1] and RadarGun [2].

[1] - https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/

[2] - https://github.com/radargun/radargun